# parse multiline varchar field into rows (T-sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am making a report in SSRS. Database contains table "Project" with a "Notes" field which is formated by users in this way:

```
#Completed
-line 1 description
-line 2 description
-line3 and so on

#Planned
-line 1 etc.

#Risks
- line1 ...etc
```

There are always only those 3 categories and in that order. Bullet points can be from 0 to unlimited (but i never seen more than 10)

I would like to get output(dataset)  in format (so I can group them in tablix):
    ProjectID, Maincategory, itemID, subcategories.
For example

```
1   |   Completed  |  1  |   line1 
1   |   Completed  |  2  |   line2
1   |   Completed  |  3  |   line3
...
1   |   Planned    |  1  |   Line1
...
1   |   Risks      |  1  |   line1
...
```

I cant change source DB so I cant create stored procedure, it should be regular query.
I looked at various solutions with CTE recursions but I just cant figure out how they work in oreder to change them for my case.

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't SSRS have a multi-line text box which would do this for you?

Comment: Are you asking how to split a string into rows on a line break? Would this help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco